# How to start developing operating system in smartcard

Tags: operating-system, smartcard

Currently I was looking on some guideline how to start developing my own smartcard operating system from scratch but until now i have no luck to find a clue where to start it.

I did a lot of research on google but still didn't find the clue.

I have some basic on smartcard programming like developing an applet for java card. mostly i will use nxp jcop to install my application. I also do a lot of programming in .net platform on how to interfacing with the smartcard.

Hopefully by posting this, i shall able to find some clue on how to start my programming in developing smartcard operating system

Comment: In the end smart cards are just processor cards, so if you find out the processor architecture you can probably find a C compiler for it. You'll need information about boot loaders as well. There are many smart card OS manufacturers, but most of them are or have been taken over by *big* companies. So you're asking something akin to "how to build a plane from scratch". Maybe reach out to one of the smaller fabs and ask them?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes its possible if there is something like a generic smart card OS that i can refer for starting? Do you know any smallers fabs that I can ask? Thanks